# Maven build with a plugin getting timed out

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-plugin

I have created a maven plugin which will do an installation and start process of an application during maven build. After the application gets started it will listen for the request and serves it,until it gets killed. My problem is that upto starting the application and serving request it works fyn but the start process is not listening after sometime it gets timeout and says build success.

What will be the cause of it? If i do the same installation and start process in commandline it works fyn. But in maven it some how get timeout and says build success.

Comment: try to run your build with -X flag and check if `errors` you see on eclipse cmd.

Comment: @ArdeshanaMilan : There are no errors.. it is building sucessfully.. the start process listends for around 30 seconds after that it comes out of the program and says print sucess

Comment: I guess maven internally shutdown the jvm after some amount of time....